# Add Array to field instead of String

Tags: directus

I have the following problem:

I want to add my field `value` the value of `value= [0,16,33,50,67,84,101,118,135,152,169,186,203,220,237,254,271,288,305,322,338,355,372,389,406,423,440,457,474,491,508,525,542,559,576,593,610,627,644,661,677,694,711,728,745,762,779,796,813,830,847,864,881,898,915,932,949,966,983,1000,1016,1033,1050,1067,1084,1101,1118,1135,1152,1169,1186,1203,1220,1237,1254,1271,1288,1305,1322,1338,1355,1372,1389,1406,1423,1440,1457,1474,1491,1508,1525,1542,1559,1576,1593,1610,1627,1644,1661,1677]`

I tried to use JSON or any other field type it return me the value as a string (with "") and as I am doing stuff, it would not work. How to work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this answers your question, but Directus 6 saves data in only the MySQL 5 datatypes. Therefore, CSV / JSON values are saved as strings (often in the TEXT datatype). If you want to use this data in your application as an array / JSON, you will have to convert it yourself.

The Directus team is working to support more (custom) datatypes in future versions, so the API can respond with nested arrays/objects in JSON.